different colors for equations with cref
I was working on some equations and wish to have them in a different hyperlink color compared to the rest of the link colors I set in my \hypersetup. Now, it appears this post does what I'm looking for if not for the exclusion of the equation () part of the link which are still in the original color set in the \hypersetup.
Is there a way to get the whole text in teal (or any other color)? Thanks in advance, below a MWE and the related output:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}


\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=electricultramarine,
    filecolor=.,
    linkcolor=maroon,
    urlcolor=smokyblack,
    linktoc=all
}
\definecolor{teal}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.5}
\definecolor{cobalt}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67}
\definecolor{maroon}{rgb}{0.69, 0.19, 0.38}
\definecolor{coolblack}{rgb}{0.0, 0.18, 0.39}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.83, 0.83, 0.83}
\definecolor{smokyblack}{rgb}{0.06, 0.05, 0.03}
\definecolor{ceruleanblue}{rgb}{0.16, 0.32, 0.75}
\definecolor{electricultramarine}{rgb}{0.25, 0.0, 1.0}

\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{subsection}{subsection}{subsections}
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{(\textcolor{teal}{#1})}#3}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Methods}
\dots
\section{Population genetics and Demographic Inference}
\dots
\subsection{PCA and other exploratory population genetic analyses} \label{exploratory}

This is the method subsection for exploratory analyses.

\chapter{Results}
\dots
\section{Exploratory population genetics analyses}

\dots This value, known as Watterson estimator (or $\theta$ Watterson) <citation>, is expressed by the following equation with the number of polymorphic sites set as K:
\begin{equation} \label{equation:1}
\widehat{\theta}_w = \frac{K}{a_n} \text{, with } a_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i}
\end{equation}

When I use a normal \texttt{cleveref} I get the expected output in: \textbf{\Cref{exploratory}}; on the other hand, even following the example in the post, I cannot get rid of the maroon hyperlink color for the equation and brackets part of the text when linking an equation: \textbf{\cref{equation:1}}.

\end{document}



Use \crefformat which is the whole reference with prefix not only the label:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=electricultramarine,
    filecolor=.,
    linkcolor=maroon,
    urlcolor=smokyblack,
    linktoc=all
}
\definecolor{teal}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.5}
\definecolor{cobalt}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67}
\definecolor{maroon}{rgb}{0.69, 0.19, 0.38}
\definecolor{coolblack}{rgb}{0.0, 0.18, 0.39}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.83, 0.83, 0.83}
\definecolor{smokyblack}{rgb}{0.06, 0.05, 0.03}
\definecolor{ceruleanblue}{rgb}{0.16, 0.32, 0.75}
\definecolor{electricultramarine}{rgb}{0.25, 0.0, 1.0}

\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{subsection}{subsection}{subsections}
\crefformat{equation}{\textcolor{teal}{equation~#2\textcolor{teal}{(#1)}#3}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Methods}
\dots
\section{Population genetics and Demographic Inference}
\dots
\subsection{PCA and other exploratory population genetic analyses} \label{exploratory}

This is the method subsection for exploratory analyses.

\chapter{Results}
\dots
\section{Exploratory population genetics analyses}

\dots This value, known as Watterson estimator (or $\theta$ Watterson) <citation>, is expressed by the following equation with the number of polymorphic sites set as K:
\begin{equation} \label{equation:1}
\widehat{\theta}_w = \frac{K}{a_n} \text{, with } a_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i}
\end{equation}

When I use a normal \texttt{cleveref} I get the expected output in: \textbf{\Cref{exploratory}}; o[![enter image description here][1]][1]n the other hand, even following the example in the post, I cannot get rid of the maroon hyperlink color for the equation and brackets part of the text when linking an equation: \textbf{\cref{equation:1}}.

\end{document}


The outer \textcolor changes the general color, but this is overwritten by the hyperref link generated by #2 and #3. To change that color again the inner \textcolor between #2 and #3 is also needed. The ~ is a non-breakable space between the prefix and the link.
If you want the prefix be part of the link, you can use:
\crefformat{equation}{#2\textcolor{teal}{equation~(#1)}#3}

See the cleveref manual for more information about how \crefformat works.

great! Thanks a lot, I kind of intuitively attempted something similar but for one I wasn't using crefformat also I didn't put the ~ symbol. Could you tell me how they work/make things happen? Thanks again!

@Matteo I've added some more information. If you have additional questions please ask a new/follow-up question. Comments are not suitable for questions.

much appreciated!

I think it would be a good idea to change equation~#2\textcolor{teal}{(#1)}#3} to equation~#2\textcolor{teal}{\textup{(#1)}}#3}, to guarantee that the equation number and surrounding parentheses will always be rendered in upright lettering.

@Mico I see, thanks. Also as a "side effect" the tweak cabohah suggested disables the link on the word equation, which is supposed to be in the hyperlink due to the nameinlink specification of cleveref. Any idea on how to fix this?

Stupid question, I now understood better what cabohah intended by "prefix being part of the link". I intended to have it, as such as in my test case I included in the hyperlink. Apologies for the confusion!
